# Using Fast Bilateral Filter in Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, filter, kinect, point-cloud-library

I am trying to apply a bilateral filter to smooth 2 point clouds for registration.  Code is below:

```
pcl::FastBilateralFilter<pcl::PointXYZRGB> filter;
filter.setInputCloud(input);
filter.setSigmaS(5);
filter.setSigmaR(5e-3);
filter.applyFilter(*output);
```

The result is an empty point cloud, and I can't seem to figure out why.  Other people have used this approach with good success.  I have tried manipulating my SigmaS and SigmaR values based on what I found in this paper (http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/bf_course/course_notes.pdf), but there is no change in the output.  Any thoughts on why this is?  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My input cloud was messed up in the sense that it was not an "organized point cloud"; that is, there was not a relationship between two given points in my Point Cloud.  The Bilateral Filter in PCL requires the input point cloud to be organized.  [Click here for more info.](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/basic_structures.php)

Since I am using the Kinect v2, I have the ability to generate organized Point Clouds; and indeed, I initialized it to be organized.  Somewhere later in my code, I used the cloud->clear() command which deleted all of the height, width, and isDense information in the Point Cloud; however, my original intention was to just delete the data points so I could add new points in.

Answer (score 0):

libfreenect2 already has a kinectv2 edge aware bilateral filter